# PHPWORD - How to insert text or image in existing word file at a specified position

Tags: php, phpword

I started using PHPWORD, to read a word doc and add some text/images at specific position in the word file. But it keeps adding at the end of file. Here is my code:

```
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load("mydoc.docx");
foreach($phpWord->getSections() as $section) {
   $textrun = $section->addTextRun('Heading1');
   $textrun->addText('Text1');
}
write($phpWord, "newdoc.docx", $writers);
```

Can anyone help me understanding of how to insert it at proper place?